# Replacing a for loop with something more efficient when comparing dates to a list

Tags: python

**Edit:** Title changed to reflect `map` not being more efficient than a `for` loop.

**Original title:** Replacing a for loop with map when comparing dates

I have a list of sequential dates `date_list` and a data frame `df` which contains, *for the purposes of now*, contains one column named `Event Date` which contains the date that an event occured:

```
Index Event Date
0     02-01-20
1     03-01-20
2     03-01-20
```

I want to know how many *events* have happened by a given date in the format:

```
Date     Events
01-01-20   0
02-01-20   1
03-01-20   3
```

My current method for doing so is as follows:

```
for date in date_list:
    event_rows = df.apply(lambda x: True if x['Event Date'] > date else False , axis=1)
    event_count = len(event_rows[event_rows == True].index)
    temp = [date,event_count]  
    pre_df_list.append(temp)
```

Where the list `pre_df_list` is later converted to a dataframe.

This method is slow and seems inelegant but I am struggling to find a method that works.

I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
map(lambda x,y: True if x > y else False, df['Event Date'],date_list)
```

but that would compare each item in the list in pairs which is not what I'm looking for.

I appreaciate it might be odd asking for help when I have working code but I'm trying to cut down my reliance of loops as they are somewhat of a crutch for me at the moment. Also I have multiple different events to track in the full data and looping through ~1000 dates for each one will be *unsatisfyingly* slow.

Comment: `map` is still a loop, for the purpose of efficiency

Comment: In general `True if <condition> else False` does not make any sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, I'll edit the question to reflect this

Comment: @KlausD.could you explain why please?

Comment: ```lambda x, y: x > y``` is preferrable. ```x > y``` calls ```x.__gt__(self, y)``` and this returns ```bool```.

Comment: It's the same as just `<condition>`. Even in a case where you want to make a "trueish" value a real boolean, you just use `bool(<condition>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby()` and `size()` to get counts per date and `cumsum()` to get a cumulative sum, i.e. include all the dates before a particular row.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import random
import pandas as pd 

# example data
dates = [date(2020, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=random.randrange(1, 100, 1)) for _ in range(1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event Date': dates})

# count events <= t
event_counts = df.groupby('Event Date').size().cumsum().reset_index()
event_counts.columns = ['Date', 'Events']
event_counts


          Date  Events
0   2020-01-02      13
1   2020-01-03      23
2   2020-01-04      34
3   2020-01-05      42
4   2020-01-06      51
..         ...     ...
94  2020-04-05     972
95  2020-04-06     981
96  2020-04-07     989
97  2020-04-08     995
98  2020-04-09    1000
```

Then if there's dates in your `date_list` file that don't exist in your dataframe, convert the `date_list` into a dataframe and merge the previous results. The `fillna(method='ffill')` will fill gaps in the middle of the data, whille the last `fillna(0)` incase there's gaps at the start of the column.

```
date_list = [date(2020, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(150)]
date_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_list})

merged_df = pd.merge(date_df, event_counts, how='left', on='Date')
merged_df.columns = ['Date', 'Events']

merged_df = merged_df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
```

Comment: That works perfectly and its much much faster, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken about your objective, it seems to me that you can simply use pandas DataFrames' ability to compare against a single value and slice the dataframe like so:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'event_date': [date(2020,9, 1), date(2020, 9, 2), date(2020, 9, 3)]})
>>> df
   event_date
0  2020-09-01
1  2020-09-02
2  2020-09-03
>>> df[df.event_date > date(2020, 9, 1)]
   event_date
1  2020-09-02
2  2020-09-03
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to know the cumulative amount of events that have occurred by each date as more than one row can have the same event date, I will edit the question to be clearer